# PRNG-like seeded hash function

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, random, hash, cryptography

I want two clients using the same "seed" to generate the same number by inputting a time stamp or long number, returning a float like using random().

For example w/ the function: hasher(String seed, long input);

```
 hasher("StackOverflow", 1000000010); //returns 0.57217329503213..
 hasher("StackOverflow", 1000000010); //returns 0.57217329503213...
 hasher("StackOverflowz", 1000000010); //returns 0.15689784654554...
 hasher("StackOverflow", 97494849465); //returns 0.456944151561...
```

It really isn't supposed to be secure or private, but just random enough. I figured I could use bit manipulation, but I'm by no means an expert at either hashing or bit manipulation.

I realize seed is pretty much redundant as combining seed and input, but I suppose it'd help to know the best way to implement a seed in it without compromising reliability.
Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: A pretty stupid approach will be using the `input` as salt for an MD5 algorithm, and interpreting any part of the MD5 hash as mantissa for a 1-based number.

Comment: +1 for Vesper - that'd work.  If you break the problem down, you can make it even simpler by taking any hash function "`h`" for a string where the maximum value it might return is say M (for example, that might be 2^32-1 for a 32-bit hash): then simply `h(seed + input.toString()) / parseFloat(M)`.

Answer (score 1):

I made a small implementation, but beware that JavaScript is far from my primary language. The code requires CryptoJS for the hash functionality.

```
function hasher(a, b) {
    hash = fromHex(CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(CryptoJS.SHA256(a + b)));    
    // warning: only about 32 bit precision
    hashAsDouble = intFromBytes(hash.slice(0, 4)) * (1.0 / 4294967296.0);
    return hashAsDouble;
}

function fromHex(hex) {
    a = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < hex.length; i += 2) {
        a.push("0x" + hex.substr(i, 2));
    }
    return a;
}

function intFromBytes(x) {
    if (x.length != 4) {
        return null;
    }

    var val = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        val = val << 8;
        val = val + (x[i] & 0xFF);
    }
    return toUint32(val);
}

function modulo(a, b) {
    return a - Math.floor(a / b) * b;
}

function toUint32(x) {
    return modulo(toInteger(x), Math.pow(2, 32));
}

function toInteger(x) {
    x = Number(x);
    return x < 0 ? Math.ceil(x) : Math.floor(x);
}
```

Comment: I had a lot of trouble with the JS type system creating this answer. Be aware of the issues in the type system if you want to use this answer (or Java Script in general) to create anything safe (this comment was *slightly* more opinionated before, after spending too much time getting JS to do what I wanted it to do).